# disable Windows 10 random wallpaper (not activated OS)

Tags: windows, windows-registry, desktop-customization

there is a problem on one pc with not activated Windows 10. It automatically randomly changes wallpaper. If I go to personalize settings I can see it says wallpaper: presentation, album: Madagaskar.
Obviously I can't change these settings because windows is not activated (perfectly functional otherwise)
I removed the folders with photos from library pictures (it's on E: drive), but still Windows finds it and uses it for wallpapers.

I found the string Madagaskar in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers. I tried changing BackgroundType from 2 to 1 or 0 in registry
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers

but nothing changed. Deleting this key makes it reappear after logoff/login.
Any idea how to make this wallpaper change stop or change it to solid color?

Comment: +1. We can learn something interesting from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright I admit it's a bit of a hack. I found that the current wallpaper is in file TranscodedWallpaper. It is possible to replace this file and deny changes to it. That's it.

Comment: maybe this software would do it too https://johnsad.ventures/software/backgroundswitcher/